# Is the gstreamer-java 1.6 compatible with gstreamer 1.6.1 windows binaries

Tags: gstreamer, java-gstreamer

Do anyone have any idea if the gstreamer-java-1.6.jar downloadable from  https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/downloads/list is compatible with gstreamer windows 1.6.1 binaries? I installed both and setup the eclipse environment but somehow it gives me the warning for all(assuming as lot of warnings are on the eclipse console) the gstreamer plugins.

(javaw.exe:9744): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgio.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgio.dll': The specified module could not be found..............

Although I can see everything is fine from command prompt running gstreamer(creating sample pipeline etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any other, it will be helpful that gstreamer-1.6 compatible java bindings are there and available on https://github.com/praxis-live/praxis/tree/master/lib.gst1-java-core/release/modules/ext.
See reply on java-gstreamer forum.

*No, it isn't! 
The new home of the Java bindings is at https://github.com/gstreamer-java 
The old GStreamer-Java only supports GStreamer 0.10.  Try 
gst1-java-core at https://github.com/gstreamer-java/gst1-java-core 
There are no pre-built binaries there, although you can get my one 
from Praxis LIVE - 
https://github.com/praxis-live/praxis/tree/master/lib.gst1-java-core/release/modules/ext 
 Click on it, then click view raw and you can download it. 
It's still a work in progress, and I haven't tested on Windows yet, 
although others may have. 
Best wishes, 
Neil*